# In a node app is there a way to avoid having to list the processes on a port then kill them when address is already in use?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, apollo, apollo-server

What I am frequently running into is after ending a react or express app & if I restart it I am getting the message `EADDRINUSE: address already in use ::Port#`. So then we can list the processes on that port by `lsof -i :3000` then `kill -9 1111` and then the port is free & the app can start again.

What I am wondering if there is a node package or some way to avoid having to go though those steps and when the app is stopped the processes/port are free and I don't have to find the processes & kill them?

Comment: If it's your own code and an http server on the port, you could make a private route on that server that will kill itself (with `process.exit()`) when requested.  The route could be coded to only accept the kill request from 127.0.0.1 and/or to require certain credentials in a custom header to keep outsiders from using it.

Comment: An advantage of this scheme is that you don't need elevated privileges to send the http request.  You just have to make sure you are properly blocking that request from being used by any outside agent.

Comment: If it's not your server code using the port, then  you will need to find the appropriate process id and run `kill` in a shell with appropriate privileges.

Comment: wow thatnks @jfriend00; yes it's my local host server running code locally; so I will look into how to implement the private route that kills itself with process.exit(); that sounds like an option